# Java Is this multiple inheritance? Or acceptable to do?

Tags: java, inheritance

Is it okay for the gameworld to extend AnimationTimer and then have different maps inherit from Gameworld?

```
public abstract class GameWorld extends AnimationTimer{}

public class Maze extends GameWorld {}
public class BossMap extends GameWorld {}
```

Comment: Why don't you compile this code and see for yourself if it is allowed or not?

Comment: That is not multiple inheritance.  In fact in Java it's extremely common to have multiple concrete subclasses of an abstract superclass like that.

Comment: Multiple inheritance would be something like `class Maze extends GameWorld, BossMap {}`. Which you may find out is prevented by the compiler.

Comment: From what I read that was how I interpreted it but just wanted to clarify thanks

Comment: I recommend doing some research into some basic tutorials, or googling it more as there will be plenty of information for this online. You will learn very slowly if every time you have a slight hiccup you resort to asking a question online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thats totally fine.

Every instance of Maze is now an instance of Gameworld and every instance of Gameworld is now an instance of AnimationTimer.

=> Every instance of Maze is also an instance fo AnimationTimer.

Comment: EDIT: I didnt see the use of "multiple inheritance" in the title.
So, your code is fine, although calling it multiple inheritance is wrong as the others pointed out already.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you have there is absolutely fine. It is not multiple inheritance. Each class has only one direct parent.

Multiple inheritance is not possible in Java. But it does support multilevel inheritance. However, as well as extending one class you can implement as many interfaces as you wish which allows a class to be polymorphic (i.e. Be more than one type of thing at the same time).

Answer (score 2):

Marvin is right, I just wanted to add, when you use inheritance it's really nice to remember the is-a test.  You are claiming that Maze and BossMap are both GameWorlds. I believe this is true (although calling it a game "World" might be a tad misleading, I'd say they were game "Map"s)

Multiple Inheritance would be if you said a BossMap is-a Gameworld AND BossMap is-a "AnimationTimer" (Directly).  This is quite possible but leads to problems and Java disallows is-a relationships from two parents because of the problems that often come up.

Your solution is fine, but may cause an unnecessarily close relationships between the objects.

The other solution is Java interfaces.  Interfaces are a "has-a" relationship.  A BossMap could Have-a Gameworld and have-a TimedEvent.  a Gameworld can also have-a TimedEvent.  Interfaces will always work and are generally easier to understand.

Because the Has-a relationship is "looser" and therefore often easier to understand/deal with, we generally suggest that you prefer implements (interface) over extends (inherit) but that's a balance--you'll figure out your own preferences over time.